# HDD partition help

Tags: partitioning, dual-boot

I have 4 OS's on my dual boot system: backtrack 5, Windows 7, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and Lubuntu. My win7 OS is kinda broken (I hate windows now :P), and I am now using my Ubuntu installation.

I only have 14GB of free space, and I would like more. So, I need to take some from my Windows installation, and give it to my Ubuntu OS. Bear in mind I need to keep my windows system intact, I need to take about 20GB if possible.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/
Try shrinking a partition and then expand ubuntu partition. That's all I know

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.